# Python check if list items are integers?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have a list which contains numbers and letters in string format.

```
mylist=['1','orange','2','3','4','apple']
```

I need to come up with a new list which only contains numbers:

```
mynewlist=['1','2','3','4']
```

If I have a way to check if each item in list can be converted to Integer, I should be able to come up with what I want by doing something like this:

```
for item in mylist:
    if (check item can be converted to integer):
        mynewlist.append(item)
```

How do I check that a string can be converted to an integer? Or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
mynewlist = [s for s in mylist if s.isdigit()]
```

---

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> **`str.isdigit()`**
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

---

As noted in the comments, `isdigit()` returning `True` does not necessarily indicate that the string can be parsed as an int via the `int()` function, and it returning `False` does not necessarily indicate that it cannot be. Nevertheless, the approach above should work in your case.

Comment: It's worth noting `str.isdigit()` will return `True` on some things that will throw exceptions when passed through `int()`, and `False` on some things that won't. E.g: superscript numbers, "+1".

Comment: @Lattyware Can you give an example of values that may cause exception?

Comment: "²" - the superscript digit 2. It returns `True` from `str.isdigit()`, but `int("²")` will throw a `ValueError`. In reverse, `"+1"` will parse fine, but `str.isdigit("+1")` will return `False`.

Comment: @Lattyware Obviously this is the case for negative integers too.

Comment: @squiguy Of course, there are plenty of such cases, I just gave two simple examples.

Comment: Of course (in Python 2.x) `'020'` will pass _both_ tests, and yet still probably won't be what the OP wanted…

Answer (score 14):

Fast, simple, but maybe not always right:

```
>>> [x for x in mylist if x.isdigit()]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

More traditional if you need to get numbers:

```
new_list = []
for value in mylist:
    try:
        new_list.append(int(value))
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

**Note**: The result has integers. Convert them back to strings if needed,
replacing the lines above with:

```
try:
    new_list.append(str(int(value)))
```

Comment: but what if you want to ignore numbers as strings '123' for example, currently you include them

Answer (score 10):

You can use exceptional handling as `str.digit` will only work for integers and can fail for something like this too:

```
>>> str.isdigit(' 1')
False
```

Using a generator function:

```
def solve(lis):                                        
    for x in lis:
        try:
            yield float(x)
        except ValueError:    
            pass

>>> mylist = ['1','orange','2','3','4','apple', '1.5', '2.6']
>>> list(solve(mylist))                                    
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.5, 2.6]   #returns converted values
```

or may be you wanted this:

```
def solve(lis):
    for x in lis:
        try:
            float(x)
            return True
        except:
            return False
...         
>>> mylist = ['1','orange','2','3','4','apple', '1.5', '2.6']
>>> [x for x in mylist if solve(x)]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '1.5', '2.6']
```

or using `ast.literal_eval`, this will work for all types of numbers:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> def solve(lis):
    for x in lis:
        try:
            literal_eval(x)
            return True
        except ValueError:   
             return False
...         
>>> mylist=['1','orange','2','3','4','apple', '1.5', '2.6', '1+0j']
>>> [x for x in mylist if solve(x)]                               
['1', '2', '3', '4', '1.5', '2.6', '1+0j']
```

Comment: Note the behaviour of this is different to what the OP stated - the OP showed the elements of the list remaining as strings. That said, it's *probably* the best answer in most cases. Also, the use of `float()` is probably good, but if the asker only wants whole integer values, `int()` is apporpriate.

Answer (score 6):

The usual way to check whether something can be converted to an `int` is to `try` it and see, following the [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle:

```
try:
    int_value = int(string_value)
except ValueError:
    # it wasn't an int, do something appropriate
else:
    # it was an int, do something appropriate
```

So, in your case:

```
for item in mylist:
    try:
        int_value = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        mynewlist.append(item) # or append(int_value) if you want numbers
```

---

In most cases, a loop around some trivial code that ends with `mynewlist.append(item)` can be turned into a list comprehension, generator expression, or call to `map` or `filter`. But here, you can't, because there's no way to put a `try`/`except` into an expression.

But if you wrap it up in a function, you can:

```
def raises(func, *args, **kw):
    try:
        func(*args, **kw)
    except:
        return True
    else:
        return False

mynewlist = [item for item in mylist if not raises(int, item)]
```

… or, if you prefer:

```
mynewlist = filter(partial(raises, int), item)
```

---

It's cleaner to use it this way:

```
def raises(exception_types, func, *args, **kw):
    try:
        func(*args, **kw)
    except exception_types:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This way, you can pass it the exception (or tuple of exceptions) you're expecting, and those will return `True`, but if any *unexpected* exceptions are raised, they'll propagate out. So:

```
mynewlist = [item for item in mylist if not raises(ValueError, int, item)]
```

… will do what you want, but:

```
mynewlist = [item for item in mylist if not raises(ValueError, item, int)]
```

… will raise a `TypeError`, as it should.