# Fix errors for checking integers in lists

Tags: python, list, integer

When I run this code; even when the list contains only numbers, it still returns as an error when it should return `[1, 2, 3]`. How can I fix this issue?

```
def check_integer(a, b, c):

  if type([a, b, c]) !=  int:
    raise TypeError("Must be numbers.")
  else:
    return [a, b, c]

print (check_integer(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: You check types using `is` keyword and not `==`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all elements of a list are of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-of-the-same-type)

Comment: You are passing a list and checking wihether it is int or not. Your logic is incorrect

Comment: `type([1,2,3])` is a `list`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908186/python-check-if-list-items-are-integers

Answer (score 1):

try using `all` and iterate over each elements:

```
def check_integer(a, b, c):

    if not all(type(i)==int for i in [a,b,c]):
        raise TypeError("Must be numbers.")
    else:
        return [a, b, c]

print (check_integer(1, 2, 3))
```

---

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Efficient way of doing:

```
def check_integer(*params):

    if not all(type(i)==int for i in params):
        raise TypeError("Must be numbers.")
    else:
        return params

print (check_integer(*[1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_integer(a, b, c):

  if not (type(a) is int and type(b) is int and type(c) is int):
    raise TypeError("Must be numbers.")
  else:
    return [a, b, c]


print(check_integer(1, 2, 3))
```

this is
correct code.

Answer (score 0):

A generalized solution:

```py
def check_integer(*args):
    if not all([type(i) == int for i in [*args]]):
        raise TypeError("Must be numbers.")

    return args
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```py
def check_integers(*args):

    if not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in args):
        raise TypeError("Must be numbers.")
    
    return list(args)
```

You can add other types in the second argument of `isinstance` as a tuple (ej. `isinstance(var, (int, float))`).